# How to set different responsive layout with w3.css?

Tags: css, responsive, w3.css

I'd like to set two different responsive layouts (with w3.css):

1. For mobile (small) and medium device
2. For large device

I don't want to repeat my code just to specify a different responsive layout.

My code is like:

```
<div class="w3-content">
    <div class="w3-row-padding">
        <div class="w3-third">
           [...]
        </div>
        <div class="w3-twothird">
           [...]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to show `w3-third` over `w3-twothird` on small and medium devices.

Thanks

Comment: Oh god, w3schools created a *framework?* [Here's the responsive documentation you're looking for](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_grid.asp)

Comment: Yes, it's nice... I've already seen that link, but I can find a way to diferetiate mobile and medium device.

Comment: It's literally the first example on that page.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I was looking [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_responsive.asp) and I believe your link was the same... Thanks